# How to make transaction only effect in a method when a annotated Transactional is added in both class and method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I had an interview, and during the interview, I was asked the following question: When the `@Transactional` annotation is added to both the class and one method, but not on other methods, how can I only make the transaction of this method effective?

For example:

```
@Transactional
public class ClassA {

     @Transactional
     private void methodA() {
     } 

     private void methodB() {
     }

     private void methodC() {
     }
}
```

So, how can I make sure that the other transactions within the class do not take effect? What does this question focus on?

Comment: I do not understand your question. The annotation at the class level affects all methods. The annotation at the method level overwrites a possible class level annotation.

Comment: What did interview mean by `effective`? In given example nothing will change. Denoting both class and method by identical annotations will not make any difference. The difference will only happen when two annotations are different, for example `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` on a method will override the annotation inherited from the class-level (`@Transactional`).

Answer (score 3):

You can change the propagation type of the inner transaction:

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

This will create a new inner transaction and suspend the outer transaction. This might be useful if you need an inner transaction to commit, but you need the outer transaction to still rollback if there are any issues elsewhere.

I have never used a class-scoped `@Transactional`, but the `propagation` property is actually pretty useful to know about.

I have used it in several cases to override the default, `Propagation.REQUIRED`, which says: 'create a new transaction if one does not already exist - otherwise **support** the current transaction',  according to the docs.

By the way, I am using:

`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

So my answer does not apply if you are using an alternative `@Transactional`

Also note that the inner and outer transaction distinction is HQL-based, so you don't need to worry about the SQL dialect you're using.